# Discord error code 50006: Cannot send an empty message (Although message is displayed on terminal)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to build a simple Discord bot which finds information about a specific stock when its name or symbol is inputted by the user. I included my code which web-scraped all the data into another document, but it's included in my `bot.py` file. I have it set up so that when I type `viewall`, a list of all the stocks should appear. However, when typing that command in my Discord server, I get nothing. However, the output on my terminal is:

```
...
497                          IPG Photonics Corporation   IPGP  0.015348   172.27  -0.25  (-0.14%)
498                   Ralph Lauren Corporation Class A     RL  0.014038   117.93   0.47   (0.40%)
499                            Fox Corporation Class B    FOX  0.012540    34.72   0.34   (0.99%)
500                          Under Armour Inc. Class A    UAA  0.009869    21.04  -0.04  (-0.19%)
501                             Discovery Inc. Class A  DISCA  0.009597    24.38   0.51   (2.14%)
502                                           Gap Inc.    GPS  0.009013    17.90   0.25   (1.42%)
503                          Under Armour Inc. Class C     UA  0.008749    17.99   0.05   (0.28%)
504                           News Corporation Class B    NWS  0.006916    22.71  -0.06  (-0.26%)
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 33, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

I deduce that there's no problems with my stocks file, as the `viewall` command did what I wanted, but then I receive that error, so I'm not entirely sure what it means or what I did wrong. This is my current `bot.py` file:

```py
# bot.py
import os
import SandPwebscraper as stocks      # Python file web-scraping stock data

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    

    if message.content == 'viewall':
        response = stocks.viewall()
        await message.channel.send(response)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

**EDIT**

The following lines

```py
response = stocks.viewall()
messageToSend = str(response[0])
await message.channel.send(messageToSend)
```

were added instead of

```py
response = stocks.viewall()
await message.channel.send(response)
```

However I get this (what I can assume can be syntax) error after my list is printed in terminal:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 33, in on_message
    messageToSend = str(response[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

If it is a syntax error, I'm not entirely sure what I've written wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just my guess, but maybe variable response is not detected as a string.
What you may want to try:

```
response = stocks.viewall()
messageToSend = str(response[0])
await message.channel.send(messageToSend)
```

Hope it works. It's most probable that response is not a string which is why message.channel.send says that it returns empty message

From the documentation:
[image]

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.channel.send

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that fixed something, but a new error has appeared. I included it in my og post. From what I can tell this seems to be a syntax error, but I'm not sure what?

Comment: Oh, I put response[0] because I thought that response is a list. If it is not, then just use:
messageToSend = str(response)

Comment: A good thing to understand is that with print, you can display a lot of data types. For example if you were to have dictionary, list, string, int. You can just do print(data).  But for the function send() it only accepts string as said in the documentation. So it'd be good to know what is the data type of your variable.

Comment: Ok yeah thanks again, I really appreciate your help. Now I don't get any errors, however, the bot prints out `None` on the server, but prints the desired output on the terminal. I don't think it's character limit as I even tested with one row at a time and bot still prints `None`...

Comment: How about trying print(str(response))?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but still thanks for your help